# How do I grant access to an Azure AD user?

Tags: windows-10, azure-activedirectory

I've joined my laptop to my Azure AD domain.  When I type 'whois', I get 'AzureAd\azureuser'.  I now have a file that I want to access.  I go to the file permissions screen:

[image]

It will not recognize my azure user (nor does it allow me to select azuread in the 'Location...' box).  All I get is this useless box:

[image]

Comment: The same you would for any users.  You specify the name of the domain the user is part of.  When you click "Check Names" what happens?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1293498/unable-to-add-myself-to-any-acl-while-using-azure-ad

Answer (score -1):

Based on my test, we can't grant direct access of on-prem resources to Windows 10 Azure AD joined devices. Member servers on your domain or local computer can't translate a request to grant permissions to an Azure AD user account.

Local admin should have no rights to change the permission with Azure Accounts, Azure accounts should be managed through Azure portal.

Comment: However, you could try to add user to local administrator group as this guide: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/janketil/2016/03/10/azuread-domain-join-add-user-to-local-adminstrator-group/

Comment: The last paragraph is completely besides the point. Because the question was not to manage an AAD account, but to grant/deny the corresponding principal, identified by a SID, access to resources or give ownership. It would be laughable to be unable to do that from the perspective of a _local_ admin. Because it's squarely within the role of an admin to decide who gets access or not. This has _nothing_ to do with the ability to manage the AAD user whom you are granting/denying access, though.

Comment: The remainder of the answer is factually wrong. Of course a local machine can lookup principals. Tools like `whoami` and `icacls` are "living" proof of it. The comment remarking to add the principal to the `BUILTIN\Administrators` alias also misses the point, because this operation requires the same ability to select a principal (it's literally the same dialog) to add to a group/alias. And so the lack of ability of that dialog to do the lookup would affect it all the same ...